# R: New column storing the name of any of the already existing ones based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Say if we have a dataframe looking like this below:

```
a    b     c     d
22   18    25    9
12   24    6     18
37   8     22    25
24   19    12    27
```

I would like to create two new columns out of these ones:
a) One column storing the name of the column in which each row gets its highest value.
b) Another one storing its highest value.

In other words, my desired output would look as follows:

```
a    b     c     d    max_col  max_val
22   18    25    9    c        25
12   24    6     18   b        24
37   8     22    25   a        37
24   19    12    27   d        27
```

How should I do to retrieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(max_col = names(df)[which.max(c_across(a:d))], max_val = max(c_across(a:d)))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c     d max_col max_val
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1    22    18    25     9 c            25
2    12    24     6    18 b            24
3    37     8    22    25 a            37
4    24    19    12    27 d            27
>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be also reached reshaping data and merging:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
      pivot_longer(-id) %>%
      group_by(id) %>% filter(value==max(value)[1]) %>%
      rename(max_col=name,max_val=value)
  ) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d max_col max_val
1 22 18 25  9       c      25
2 12 24  6 18       b      24
3 37  8 22 25       a      37
4 24 19 12 27       d      27
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(a = c(22L, 12L, 37L, 24L), b = c(18L, 24L, 8L, 
19L), c = c(25L, 6L, 22L, 12L), d = c(9L, 18L, 25L, 27L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a vectorized efficient way with `max.col` from `base R` - gets the position index of the max value in a row, which is used to extract the corresponding column name with `[` , and `pmax` to return the `max` value per row

```
mcol <- names(df)[max.col(df, 'first')]
mval <- do.call(pmax, df)
df[c('max_col', 'max_val')] <- list(mcol, mval)
```

-output

```
df
#   a  b  c  d max_col max_val
#1 22 18 25  9       c      25
#2 12 24  6 18       b      24
#3 37  8 22 25       a      37
#4 24 19 12 27       d      27
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we can use the same `max.col` and `pmax` to get the column names of the max value per row and the max value of the row

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(max_col = names(cur_data())[max.col(cur_data(), 'first')],
    max_val = invoke(pmax, select(cur_data(), where(is.numeric))))
```

-output

```
#     a  b  c  d max_col max_val 
# 1 22 18 25  9       c      25
# 2 12 24  6 18       b      24
# 3 37  8 22 25       a      37
# 4 24 19 12 27       d      27
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(22L, 12L, 37L, 24L), b = c(18L, 24L, 8L, 
19L), c = c(25L, 6L, 22L, 12L), d = c(9L, 18L, 25L, 27L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option

```
inds <- max.col(df)
df <- cbind(df,
  max_col = names(df)[inds],
  max_val = df[cbind(seq_along(inds), inds)]
)
```

which gives

```
   a  b  c  d max_col max_val
1 22 18 25  9       c      25
2 12 24  6 18       b      24
3 37  8 22 25       a      37
4 24 19 12 27       d      27
```